# Passing multiple objects to constructor function

Tags: javascript

I have a constructor function that serves to push new data to an array (in this case, `allEntries`)

```
function entry (title, info) {
    this.title = title;
    this.info = [ { name : info } ];
}
var allEntries = []
```

I'm trying to figure out how to pass multiple objects for `this.info`, something like:

```
allEntries.push( new entry( 'title one', ['info 1', 'info 2'] ) );
```

in order to obtain something like:

```
{
    title: 'title one', 
    info : [
            { name: 'info 1'},
            { name: 'info 2'}
        ]
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I fixed some obvious syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an array and iterate over it to add all items using [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
function entry (title, info) {
    this.title = title;
    this.info = [];
    info.forEach(function (infoItem) {
        this.info.push({ name : infoItem});
    }, this);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var myEntry = new entry('foobar', ['info1', 'info2']);
```

BTW: Usually, classes are named with an uppercase letter in front to be able to distinguish them from functions (which are always lowercase), so you migth want to name it "Entry".

Comment: Mind me to disagree? if `info` is an array of strings, and `this.info` should be an array of objects that have the string stored in an attribute called `name`, than yes, there is.

Comment: You're right. I overlooked the fact that he wants to pass an array of strings, and that get turned into an array of objects with `name` as the property, and the string as the value.

Comment: I'm getting the error 'cannot call method 'push' of undefined' for the this.info.push part

Comment: @cat-t: Pass `this` as second argument to `.forEach`: `info.forEach(function (infoItem){...}, this)`. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Comment: @FelixKling That's a better solution. Should he add a warning about the browser support for `Array.forEach`?

Comment: @crush: A link to MDN would suffice IMO. People can find a polyfill there.

Comment: Thanks Johannes, your answer was just what I was looking for, +1

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by approaching it differently...

http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/Nz6BD/

```
function entry () {
    this.title = null;
    this.info = [];
}

entry.prototype.setInfo = function (info) {
    this.info.push({name: info});

    return this;
};

entry.prototype.setTitle = function (title) {
    this.title = title;

    return this;
}

var e1 = (new entry)
    .setInfo('foo')
    .setInfo('bar')
    .setTitle('Hello World!');
```

Comment: Setters are unnecessary here. This does nothing that can't be accomplished with Dependency Injection.